# Update MySQL records from complex Select Statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a relatively complex mysql statement that pages through a table of 1 million records 50 at a time (where $page = 50,100,150 etc) :-

```
SELECT  t.* 
FROM (SELECT  sb_pageid 
      FROM ailab_pages 
      ORDER BY sb_pageid LIMIT $page, 50) q 
JOIN ailab_pages t ON t.sb_pageid = q.sb_pageid;
```

I need to update the UPDATED field with the current date and have tried this query:-

```
UPDATE fbdatatmp.ailab_pages_copy dest, 
       ((SELECT  t.* 
         FROM (SELECT sb_pageid 
               FROM fbdatatmp.ailab_pages_copy 
               ORDER BY sb_pageid LIMIT 0, 50) q 
         JOIN fbdatatmp.ailab_pages_copy t ON t.sb_pageid = q.sb_pageid)) src 
SET dest.updated = curdate() where dest.sb_pageid = src.sb_pageid;
```

I'm getting this error when I run the query in MySQL Workbench:-

> 10:14:09  UPDATE fbdatatmp.ailab_pages_copy dest, ((SELECT  t.* FROM
>   (SELECT sb_pageid FROM fbdatatmp.ailab_pages_copy ORDER BY sb_pageid
>   LIMIT 0, 50) q JOIN fbdatatmp.ailab_pages_copy t ON t.sb_pageid =
>   q.sb_pageid)) src    SET dest.updated = curdate() where dest.sb_pageid
>   = src.sb_pageid   Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list
>   in the sidebar.   0.190 sec

if I change the inner select to a simple select like below, it works fine but I need the query to work as above:-

```
UPDATE fbdatatmp.ailab_pages_copy dest, 
               (SELECT * 
                FROM fbdatatmp.ailab_pages_copy 
                ORDER BY sb_pageid LIMIT 0,50) src 
        SET dest.updated = curdate() where dest.sb_pageid = src.sb_pageid
```

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: On the first query, You are just selecting the same row 2 times. What is the use of that? The last query should do the same job.